# How to manage table's datagridview in C# clicking a row?

Tags: c#, datagridview

In datagridview, when we need to show value then it will display as below.

row1 >> User 1

row2 >> User 2

row3 >> User 3

I want to click user 1 and then appearing or pop up a new form (to show details) how do I manage it?

Comment: Did you try anything? Share the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in many ways. I am showing an example how to selected rows value in another form with labels as follows:

In Form2, you have to create a second constructor that will take two objects :

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string yourName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public Form2(string name, int age)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            yourName = name;
            Age = age;
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = yourName;
            label2.Text = Age.ToString();
        }
    }
```

In Form1, you create an Instance of Form2 and pass objects :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 F2 = new Form2("Jon Smith", 33);

            this.Hide();
            F2.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```